# Solve the SDE: $dX_{t} = -\alpha X_{t} dt + \alpha E\{ X_{t} \} dt + \beta dW_{t}$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I would like to solve the following SDE:

$$dX_{t}  = -\alpha X_{t} dt + \alpha E\{ X_{t} \} dt + \beta dW_{t}$$

where $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ constants. But it is giving me some trouble -- mostly because I am just beginning and unsure.

---

**My Solution So Far:**

We rewrite this equation as:

$$dX_{t} + \alpha X_{t} dt  = \alpha E\{ X_{t} \} dt + \beta dW_{t}$$

If we multiply both sides by the integrating factor:

$$ r_{t} = e^{- \int_{0}^{t} -(\alpha) ds} = e^{\alpha t} $$

we get:

$$d ( e^{\alpha t} X_{t}  )  = \alpha e^{\alpha t} E\{ X_{t} \} dt + \beta e^{\alpha t} dW_{t}$$

So if we integrate, and bring the exponential term to the RHS, we get:

$$ X_{t}   = X_{0} e^{-\alpha t} + \alpha e^{-\alpha t} E\{ X_{t} \} \int_{0}^{t} e^{\alpha s}  ds + \beta e^{-\alpha t} \int_{0}^{t} e^{\alpha s} dW_{s}$$

**^^(1)** Now I am not sure that last step is correct. I justify it because $E\{ X_{t} \}$ is not a random variable -- it is a constant. So I don't need to have something like $ \int_{0}^{t} e^{\alpha s} E\{ X_{s} \} ds$, right?

Anyway, that last integral is an Ito integral, and I am not sure how to solve it exactly. However I know that, using integration by parts, we have:

$$\int_{0}^{t} e^{\alpha s} dW_{s} = e^{\alpha s}W_{s}|_{0}^{t} - \alpha \int_{0} ^{t} e^{\alpha s} W_{s} ds  = e^{\alpha t}W_{t} - \alpha \int_{0} ^{t} e^{\alpha s} W_{s} ds $$

And we have:

$$\int_{0}^{t} e^{\alpha s}  ds = \frac{e^{\alpha t}}{\alpha} - \frac{1}{\alpha} $$

So then:

$$\alpha e^{-\alpha t} E\{ X_{t} \}  \int_{0}^{t} e^{\alpha s}  ds = \alpha e^{-\alpha t} E\{ X_{t} \} [ \frac{e^{\alpha t}}{\alpha} - \frac{1}{\alpha} ] = (1 - e^{-\alpha t}) E\{ X_{t} \}$$

Thus our solution is:

$$ X_{t}   = X_{0} e^{-\alpha t} + (1 - e^{-\alpha t}) E\{ X_{t} \} + \beta e^{-\alpha t} [  e^{\alpha t}W_{t} - \alpha \int_{0} ^{t} e^{\alpha s} W_{s} ds ] $$

which is:

$$ \boxed{X_{t}   = X_{0} e^{-\alpha t} + (1 - e^{-\alpha t}) E\{ X_{t} \} + \beta W_{t} - \alpha \beta \int_{0}^{t} e^{\alpha(s-t)} W_{s} ds }$$

---

Now I want to find the mean. To do so, I write:

$$ E\{ X_{t} \}  = E  \{ X_{0} e^{-\alpha t} + (1 - e^{-\alpha t}) E\{ X_{t} \} + \beta W_{t} - \alpha \beta \int_{0}^{t} e^{\alpha(s-t)} W_{s} ds  \} $$

Since expectation is linear, we take the expectation of each term. Writing $W_{s} = W_{s} - W_{0}$, we get:

$$E \{ W_{s} \} =  E \{ W_{s} - W_{0} \} = 0  $$

Similarly, from linearity of expectation:

$$ E \{ \alpha \beta \int_{0}^{t} e^{\alpha(s-t)} W_{s} ds  \} = \alpha \beta \int_{0}^{t} e^{\alpha(s-t)} E \{ W_{s}  \}ds = 0 $$

So our expectation is:

$$ \boxed{ E\{ X_{t} \}  = e^{-\alpha t} E  \{ X_{0}  \} + (1 - e^{-\alpha t}) E\{ X_{t} \} }$$

---

Now I want to find the variance:

$$ V\{ X_{t} \} = V  \{ X_{0} e^{-\alpha t} + (1 - e^{-\alpha t}) E\{ X_{t} \} + \beta W_{t} - \alpha \beta \int_{0}^{t} e^{\alpha(s-t)} W_{s} ds   \} $$

which by the properties of the variance operator, becomes:

$$ V\{ X_{t} \} = V  \{ X_{0} e^{-\alpha t} + \beta W_{t} - \alpha \beta \int_{0}^{t} e^{\alpha(s-t)} W_{s} ds   \} $$

Now, I think I  can write:

$$ V\{ X_{t} \} = V \{ X_{0} e^{-\alpha t}  \} + V \{ \beta W_{t}  \} - V  \{ \alpha \beta \int_{0}^{t} e^{\alpha(s-t)} W_{s} ds \} $$

**^^(2)** but I am not sure of that. Anyway, writing $W_{s} = W_{s} - W_{0}$ again, gives me:

$$ V\{ X_{t} \} = e^{-2 \alpha t} V \{ X_{0}  \} + \beta^{2} T - \alpha^{2} \beta^{2} V  \{ \int_{0}^{t} e^{\alpha(s-t)} W_{s} ds  \} $$

So to evaluate the integral, I recall that $V{x} = E\{ x^{2} \} - E\{x\}^{2}$. Thus:

$$ V   \{ \int_{0}^{t} e^{\alpha(s-t)} W_{s} ds  \} = E  \{ ( \int_{0}^{t} e^{\alpha(s-t)} W_{s} ds )^{2} \} - E \{ {\int_{0}^{t} e^{\alpha(s-t)} W_{s} ds}^{2} \} $$

Bringing the expectation inside the right term, just like in the mean computation, we get that $ E \{ {\int_{0}^{t} e^{\alpha(s-t)} W_{s} ds}^{2} \} = 0$

So we are left with:

$$V   \{ \int_{0}^{t} e^{\alpha(s-t)} W_{s} ds  \} = E  \{ ( \int_{0}^{t} e^{\alpha(s-t)} W_{s} ds )^{2} \} $$

This one I am not really sure how to solve. I think I can write:

$$E  \{ ( \int_{0}^{t} e^{\alpha(s-t)} W_{s} ds )^{2} \}  = E  \{ \int_{0}^{t} e^{\alpha(s-t)} W_{s} ds \int_{0}^{t} e^{\alpha(p-t)} W_{p} dp \} = E  \{ \int_{0}^{t} \int_{0}^{t} e^{\alpha(p + s-t)} W_{p} W_{s} dp ds \} =  \int_{0}^{t} \int_{0}^{t} e^{\alpha(p + s-t)} E  \{ W_{p} W_{s} \} dp ds  = 0    $$

**^^(3)** but I am not sure of that. So then:

$$ \boxed{V\{ X_{t} \} =  e^{-2 \alpha t} V \{ X_{0}  \} + \beta^{2} T}  $$

---

Is this analysis correct? Am I going wrong somewhere? Specifically I am not sure of the steps marked (1), (2), and (3) above.

Could anyone provide some insight, or show how solve and then do the analysis for this SDE?

Thanks!

Comment: Step (1) does not look correct since you should in fact have the term $$ \int_0^t e^{\alpha s}E[X_s]\,\mathrm d s .$$ $E[X_s]$ is deterministic, but it also evolves over time, so you cannot just treat it as a constant.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist Okay, that was what I was afraid of haha. So, how would I go figure out that expression? Should it be the mean of $ dX_{t} = -\alpha X_{t} + \beta dW_{t} $ ie The SDE without the mean term? What would it be?

Comment: I think your initial derivation was mostly correct. You should find that $$ X_t = X_0 e^{-\alpha t} + \alpha \int_0^t e^{\alpha (s-t)}E[X_s]\,\mathrm ds + \beta\int_0^t e^{\alpha(s-t)} \,\mathrm d W_s. $$ Taking expectations on both sides should give you an ODE that $E[X_t]$ satisfies.

Comment: Actually, it seems that you are correct, and it turns out that $E[X_t]= E[X_0]$, so that you can treat this term as a constant. However, I think this step must be justified before you assume this.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist How did you come to that conclusion? Did you solve the mean ODE you are talking about? How would I justify it?

Comment: Yes, I found it using the ODE. Though it is also readily seen from taking expectations in (the integral form of) your original SDE. Is $X_0$ a random variable, or can you assume it is a constant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E}
   \DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}$
 We wish to solve your SDE, more commonly known as an [Ornstein-Uhlenbeck Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process), $$ \mathrm d X_t = -\alpha X_t\,\mathrm d t + \alpha \E[X_t]\,\mathrm d t + \beta\,\mathrm d W_t. \tag{SDE}\label{SDE} $$

We can proceed as you suggest by considering the auxilliary process $e^{\alpha t}X_t$, where $X$ satisfies \eqref{SDE}, so that $$ \mathrm d (e^{\alpha t} X_t) =\alpha e^{\alpha t}\E[X_t]\,\mathrm d t + \beta e^{\alpha t} \,\mathrm d W_t. \tag{1}\label{1} $$ In particular, this means that $$ e^{\alpha t}X_t = X_0 + \alpha \int_0^t e^{\alpha s} \E[X_s]\,\mathrm d s + \beta\int_0^t e^{\alpha s}\,\mathrm d W_s. $$ Taking expectations on both sides, we find that $$ e^{\alpha t} \E[X_t] = \E[X_0] + \alpha \int_0^t e^{\alpha s} \E[X_s]\,\mathrm ds. $$

Letting $Y_t = e^{\alpha t}\E[X_t]$, we see that $Y$ satisfies the differential equation $$ \frac{\mathrm d Y_t}{\mathrm d t} = \alpha Y_t, $$ which has the solution $Y_t = Y_0 \exp(\alpha t)$. Thus, $e^{\alpha t}\E[X_t] = \E[X_0] e^{\alpha t}$, so that $\E[X_t] = \E[X_0]$ for all $t\ge 0$.

We can then use \eqref{1} to find that $$ X_t = e^{-\alpha t}X_0 + \left(1 - e^{-\alpha t}\right)\E[X_0] + \beta\int_0^t e^{\alpha (s-t)}\,\mathrm d W_s. \tag{*}\label{*} $$

I don't think the solution of the SDE can become much more explicit than \eqref{*}. However, we do know that $X$ is a process with mean given by $\E[X_0]$, and, assuming that $X_0$ is independent of the Brownian motion $W$, variance $$ \Var (X_t) = e^{-2\alpha t} \Var(X_0) + \beta^2 \int_0^t e^{2\alpha(s-t)}\,\mathrm d s .$$ The form of the second term makes use of [Itô's isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_isometry).

---

As an aside, the fact that $\E[X_t] = \E[X_0]$ can be readily seen from \eqref{SDE}, which states that $$ X_t = X_0 - \alpha\int_0^t X_s \,\mathrm d s + \alpha \int_0^t \E[X_s] \,\mathrm d s + \beta W_t.$$ One can then take expectations on both sides and use Fubini's theorem to get the result.

Comment: Wow that is super helpful! I am sorry, but you could show that result of expectation as well? I will work it out myself, but I would like to see the correct answer as well. I am not sure where Fubini's theorem comes in here. I thought that was for iterated integrals haha

Comment: Right, I get that the expectation on the right most disappears. So then it becomes: $E[X_{t}] = E[X_{0}] - \alpha \int E[X_{s}] ds + \alpha \int E[X_{s}] ds = E[X_{0}]$ right?

Comment: And that final expectation in the variance is just $\int_{0}^{t} e^{2 \alpha (s-t)} dt$, right? Since it is not random.

Comment: thank you so much! Your discussion was very helpful and I learned alot.